# Which is the better way to use realpath in require_once

Tags: php

I was wondering, among the 2, which is the better way to apply `realpath` for `require_once`. I tested both, it seems no difference to me. But, I might be missing something.

```
require_once( realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) ).'/../../path/to/file.php' );
```

or

```
require_once( realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) .'/../../path/to/file.php' ));
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `realpath()` at all?

Comment: `realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) )` === `__DIR__`

Comment: May be personal preference, but I would prefer to use relative path.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this overly-complex method? To make sure that your file is included or to include it only if it exists?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I would prefer to use the second example:

```
require_once( realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) .'/../../path/to/file.php' ));
```

Mainly because I feel going up & down the structure with `../..` seems to be confusing in the long run. Especially when debugging.

But now that I am testing this in a dev environment using this code:

```
echo 'Realpath All: ' . realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) .'/../../path/to/file.php' );
echo '<br />';
echo 'Realpath Dir: ' . realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) ).'/../../path/to/file.php';
```

The output shows a flaw in using [`realpath`](https://www.php.net/realpath) for the whole path:

```
Realpath All: 
Realpath Dir: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/../../path/to/file.php
```

In cases where a typo or mistake renders the path invalid, `realpath` simply returns null. Doesn’t seem like a viable way to debug.

So I would now prefer to use this method:

```
require_once( realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) ).'/../../path/to/file.php' );
```

The effective path would be this irregardless if the path is real or not:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/../../path/to/file.php
```

Which is more useful in debugging than nothing.

Comment: Did you test literally the first case without creating the file in that path? Because that is the expected result if the file does not exist in your directory tree. Anyway, +1 for the research effort.

Comment: Not really, read my answer or the documentation, it specifies that it will return `false` if the file doesn't exist, which seems to be the case from both the test you carried and your comment.

Comment: I completely agree with that. What I meant to say is that it doesn't seem to be the best test case possible, since you already know that the file does not exist. IMO what the user wants is to require the file, assuming it exists, with a `prettier` path or one path that has more probability to include the file. I'm going to ask in the comments just in case.

Comment: Probably `require_once()` is a bigger bottleneck than both, `file_exists` and `realpath`. However I think all of them should be negligible. Post it back if you test them (:

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, first one makes not much sense actually, so I'd advise to use the second one or the already commented solutions. Why do I say this? You have this code:

```
require_once( realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) ).'/../../path/to/file.php' );
```

Which can be expanded and is equivalent to:

```
$dir = realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) );
require_once( $dir .'/../../path/to/file.php' );
```

From the documentation, we can see that `realpath() expands all symbolic links and resolves references to '/./', '/../' and extra '/' characters in the input path and returns the canonicalized absolute pathname.`. This means that you're not using realpath function for eliminating these `/../../` actually because you're doing the concatenation **after** using realpath. Thus, in the required string, those dots are still present.

Furthermore, again from the documentation, `realpath() returns FALSE on failure, e.g. if the file does not exist.` This means that, in the first case, it will simply fail if the directory is not a file. Which is basically always. So the code could be better extended to this:

```
$dir = false;
require_once( $dir . '/../../path/to/file.php' );
```

Therefore, **it will work only in those cases where the script that requires the file is in the same directory as the main executed script, being the path simply relative to this executing script**.

Note: if I didn't explain myself enough, please say so and I'll expand the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, realpath() would probably never have any effect at all, as __FILE__ is unlikely to contain things like /../ or similar. Since your path does, only the second way makes sense.

They both do work, but

```
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) .'/../../path/to/file.php' );
```

would work as well and do the same as your first example.